# Display span tag value in a textfiled

Tags: javascript, html

I am displaying a value using span tags;

JS

```
 <script>
     window.onload = function () {
         document.getElementById('tag').innerHTML = 122;
     };
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="tag"></div>
```

The value `122` gets displayed on the screen. But what i want is to display the value `122` in a `text filed`. How can i do this ?

Comment: change the tags to `<input type="text" id="tag" />` and `document.getElementById('tag').value = 122;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your html to:

```
<input type="text" id="tag">
```

And your js to:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('tag').value = 122;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an input to the DOM as `<input type="text" id="tag">` and keep your

```
javascript as window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('tag').value = 122;
};
```

This will do the job for you.

OR
Keeping your code same , you can do it as below:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tag"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function(){
    // create a textfield dynamically, say it is "text"
     document.getElementById('tag').appendChild(text);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: "But what i want is to display the value 122 in a text filed" - so your second example isn't necessary...

Comment: @Ian What I wanted to say is that he can create textfield and then append it to the div